# Navbar won't stay fixed at top after adding an effect to the body class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, frontend, navbar

```html
function setNavBarState(initialNavBarOffsetTop) {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > initialNavBarOffsetTop) {
        $('.Masthead').addClass('MastHead__Fixed__Top');
    }
    else {
        $('.Masthead').removeClass('MastHead__Fixed__Top');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    startGeneralAnimations();

    var initialNavBarOffsetTop = $('.Masthead').offset().top - 23;

    setNavBarState(initialNavBarOffsetTop);


    $(window).resize(function () {
       initialNavBarOffsetTop = $('.Masthead').offset().top - 23;
    });

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        setNavBarState(initialNavBarOffsetTop);
    });
});
```

I added a animate.css effect to the body class and now the navbar won't stay at the top of my screen when I scroll. It does get the class though!

Comment: could you add any html markup? and it would better if you could provide the code via jsfiddle

Comment: Also please include the CSS related to the masthead. It seems most likely that the issue is in the styles since including a CSS has introduced the issue.